# javax.jdo not found in my appEngine backend android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven

I am trying to implement "JDO" in my android app.

The big step in this is to integrate it into the backend endpoints implementation of my google appengine portion of the app.

In doing so, I added "jdo-api.jar" to my classpath, which made my PMF.class file error free.

However when I try to run "mvn clean install" I am still getting the error "package javax.jdo not found" - what am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're modifying the classpath in an IDE (eclipse?), but when running `mvn` you're using the maven environment defined in `pom.xml`. Try adding the jdo-api dependency to the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
 <version> ...fill in version here... </version>
</dependency>
```